# Oracle-SQL Join on Duplicate columns but avoid Duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have table 1 like this:

| id | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany |
| 1 | USA |
| 1 | Japan |
| 2 | France |

Table 2 like this

| id | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Green |
| 2 | Red |
| 2 | Yellow |

Is it possible to get result like this using SQL statement?:

| id | Country | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | Green |
| 1 | USA |  |
| 1 | Japan |  |
| 2 | France | Red |
| 2 |  | Yellow |

It means that, if id 1 has 3 countries and 1 color --> The result should return only 3 countries and 1 color in any order (and color can be in the same row with any country). Generally, if id 1 has m countries and n color --> The result should return only m countries and n colors ?
Thank you very much <3

Note: I'm using Oracle Database

Comment: On a side note: In a real database the columns should not be called ID, because they are not identifying a row in the table as the name suggests. They should instead be named according to what they represent. And only call them id_something (or something_id) when a something table exists. In your case a name like `project_number` might be appropriate. If you call the columns ID, you confuse the (human) reader.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you for u comment, this column is not called ID in my Database, i just dump the data in the post to simplify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can number your countries and colors per ID and then use a full outer join on the ID and that number:

```
with cntr as
(
  select id, row_number() over (partition by id order by country) as subid, country
  from country
)
, clr as
(
  select id, row_number() over (partition by id order by color) as subid, color
  from color
)
select id, cntr.country, clr.color
from cntr full outer join clr using (id, subid)
order by id, subid nulls last;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e74ece8cb4571d7998014f8c55bd8d7a

Comment: Thank you very much, That's great idea !

Answer (score 0):

```
with src as (
select n.id,n.country,l.color, 
(select count(id)-1 
from countries where id=n.id)  total_countries
,(
select count(id)-1
from colors where id=l.id
) total_colors
from countries  n
inner join colors  l
on n.id = l.id
)
select 
id, 
country, 
lag(color, total_countries) over (partition by id order by color) color 
from 
src 
where total_countries > 0
union all
select 
id, 
lag(country, total_colors) over (partition by id order by country) country
,color
from 
src 
where total_colors > 0
order by id, country nulls last, color nulls last
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f447193d342d725603f3e5f8de3497a)